# How can I require a custom module hosted elsewhere with its contrib dependencies being downloaded too?

Tags: 8, composer

Hi I am trying to setup my new Drupal 8 site with composer, but I got few issues.

I tried to setup the site site by following the Guide from [here](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) and was able to setup the site successfully.

After that I tried to install a custom module which is hosted on Bitbucket and I am able to download the package using Composer, but the problem is the module has some other contributed module dependency but the dependency module is not downloaded along with the custom module.

I followed the guide from [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-composerjson-file) and added composer.json file to my custom module along with the dependency, but after running `composer require custom/custom_module` only the custom module is installed but not the dependency.

My root directory composer.json file repositories section looks like this.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "custom/custom_module",
        "version": "master",
        "type": "drupal-custom-module",
        "source": {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "git@bitbucket.org:username/custom-module.git",
          "reference": "master"
        }
      }
    }
],
```

The composer.json file from the custom module is the following.

```
{
    "name": "custom/custom_module",
    "description": "This is a Custom Module with Different functionalities.",
    "type": "drupal-custom-module",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "drupal/restui": "~1.16"
    }
}
```

I also chaged the line `"drupal/restui": "~1.16"` as `"drupal/restui": "^1.16"` but with no success.

I even tried running `composer update` in the custom module directory as I was not sure whether dependencies will be installed along with custom module.
After running `composer update` in the custom module directory I got this error.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

> 

- The requested package drupal/restui could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

> Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
  see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

On Drupal.org I can find the module with that version [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/restui/releases/8.x-1.16).

**EDIT 1**

I have added below to the composer.json file from the custom module but still same issue.

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
  }
],
```

**EDIT 2** : Seems recursive package download is not possible with composer. Refer [Why can't Composer load repositories recursively?](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) and [Add support for installing libraries via asset-packagist](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/issues/278)

Comment: I don't see a composer.json file in that Drupal module (Rest UI). Are those still required?

Comment: I cant find that pacakge on packagist:
https://packagist.org/search/?q=drupal%2Frestui

Comment: They'd be on https://packages.drupal.org/8 that's why you have to declare it as a repo in your composer

Comment: I think you're right Kevin, something isn't setup right with restui. If you try doing "composer show drupal/restui" from the root of the site it cant be found so doesnt appear to exist

Comment: What Drupal version are you using?

Comment: @Kevin when I run the command composer require drupal/restui restui module got installed eventhough it doesnt have composer.json file included.
Hence I am not sure whether composer.json is required or not ?

Comment: @kiamlaluno are you asking my Drupal version? If yes I am using latest version.

Comment: I asked because the *Rest UI* module requires at least Drupal 8.2.x.

Comment: I wonder what happens when you change the `type` in both places to `drupal-module`.

Answer (score 3):

So after further looking into a way I was able to download required contributed modules while installing custom module. I am not sure if it is a correct way but it works to download dependencies.

By adding below snip to the root directory composer.json and executing

```
 composer require custom/custom_module
```

downloaded the required dependencies as well.

```
"extra": {
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json",
            "modules/*/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    }
}
```

If anyone got better suggestions please suggest.

**Note** :  The above method requires `wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin` which can be added by the below command.

```
composer require wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin
```

Comment: This one assumes the existence of the `wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin`, right? I wonder how this could be done without, since [#3069730](https://www.drupal.org/node/3069730). Related: [How do I include composer.libraries.json in root composer.json without using the wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin plugin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/298741/15055).

Comment: @leymannx you are correct it requires wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for this question I created a dummy module at https://github.com/leymannx/custom_module which has a composer.json similar to yours with `drupal/restui` in the `"require"` section and `"type": "drupal-custom-module"`.

And then in a D8 project's composer.json I adjusted the `"repositories"` section to look like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "github",
        "url":  "https://github.com/leymannx/custom_module"
    }
],
```

In the `"installer-paths"` section I added:

```
 "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"]
```

I then simply ran `composer require leymannx/custom_module` and it downloaded the module and `drupal/restui` both to the right places. Of course you now can ignore the custom module with your repo's .gitignore file.

I guess the trick was to have the `"repositories"` section adjusted like above. And I guess you also can use proper versioning for the custom module when you tagged some releases. Right now it just downloads `dev-main`.

Comment: Hi @leymannx, tried with this way still no success. For example we can consider brightcove module which has brightcove api dependency. https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later#s-installing-drupal-8-only-contributedmodule-with-drupal-9-patch dependency is not being installed here.

Comment: @miststudent2011 – Isn't this a different question then? See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/296802/15055.

Comment: @miststudent2011 – Have you also tried putting github above the  composer repositories as suggested in the doc you linked? And you replaced github and the URL with what exactly when you tried it with brighcove?

Comment: Yes, done everything as suggested in guide and linked different question. Copy pasted everything from the guide and followed the guide exactly.

Comment: > Isn't this a different question then?
Yes, but linked here so that we can find a solution, which will be common for both . Commented there as well.

Comment: @miststudent2011 – I don't get it. Brightcove isn't hosted "elsewhere". So I don't have to edit the composer.json to have any special repositories in it and when I now run `$ composer require drupal/brightcove` it downloads me the API too, of course (and the `drupal/time_formatter` as well.

Comment: The problem is Brightcove is not D ready so you need to patch it to install on D9, in order to do so we can use this guide https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later#s-installing-drupal-8-only-contributedmodule-with-drupal-9-patch , thats where the issue arises. This is gonna be the case for all D8 only modules which are being installed on D9 with patches.