# Date Field Type - Text Field Widget is Gone?

Tags: datetime, 9

I am noticing that the Date field type only has the availability of three widgets:

1. Select list
2. Date and time
3. Select list, no time

Can someone tell me why the "Text Field" widget is gone?  Or am I missing something?

I have a use case where the user needs to be able to copy the date from another source and paste that value into the date field.  It would be too time-consuming to have to pick the date from a "date picker" widget.  It would be ok if it were a one-off situation but this user needs to be able to enter several at a time.

Comment: See [Change the date format for the form display](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2646454) at the time you could still paste with Firefox, not sure if that's still the case.

Comment: Thank You @NoSssweat ! !  I am using Firefox and yes I can't paste with it.  I followed your post on drupal.org.  Do you know of a module that creates the new field formatter/input widget?

Answer (score 4):

> I have a use case where the user needs to be able to copy the date
> from another source and paste that value into the date field.

### [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_datepicker)

This will allow you to type/paste in and change the date format.

[image]

**Note:** composer won't install the library for you, you have to manually get the /dist folder [from github](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) and put in in the /libraries folder. So it has the `/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js` structure.

---

**Similar but don't quite do it**

[Datetime Flatpickr](https://www.drupal.org/project/datetime_flatpickr) Allows you to change date format, but doesn't allow you to type/paste in.

[Bootstrap DateTime Picker](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_datetime_picker) Allows you to type/paste in, but doesn't allow changing the date format.

[Single Date Time Picker](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_datetime) doesn't allow you to type/paste in nor change the time format.

Comment: Thank You for your quick response!!   But I found It won't install via Composer.  Throws a "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." error.  I also tried the Bootstrap DateTime Picker and wasn't able to install it either on 9.

Comment: @tawellman yes, because both of these modules are not D9 ready. See [Require v8 only contrib module with v9 patch](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296802/require-v8-only-contrib-module-with-v9-patch) for ways to get around that. Also, if you go with `Bootstrap Datepicker` you will need to apply [D9 compatibility patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_datepicker/issues/3147249)