# Patch drupal.org project (core/module/theme) with issue fork

Tags: 8, composer, community-official-site

The new [fork based merge request (MR) approach](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-git-to-contribute-to-drupal/creating-issue-forks-and-merge-requests) is pretty neat to get the patches created/reviewed/merged. However, if you are using the patch via [cweagans/composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches), we have a few options.

**Option 1**: we can use the MR  to add the patch like this:

```
"drupal/message": {
  "3186091": "https://git.drupalcode.org/project/message/-/merge_requests/1.patch"
}
```

but it means any new change pushed to the fork/branch, would get automatically added. As the patch file gets pulled on `composer install`.

**Option 2**:
We could use the fork's [branch](https://git.drupalcode.org/issue/message-3186091/-/tree/3186091-add-config-schema) and commit hash to keep the patch static, but once the MR merged, the fork might get deleted and breaks the build.

**Option 3**: Obviously we can generate the patch from the MR and upload to the issue comment, but it seems a duplicate effort and hard to keep up with an active core issue (right now, we just need to update the patch file in `composer.json` or `composer.patches.json`)

Is there a way to have the current patch file behavior in the new fork based issue queue?

**UPDATE**: Both option 1 and (probably) option 3 are documented on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/gitlab-integration/issue-forks-merge-requests#s-patch-files-for-use-with-composer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Require v8 only contrib module with v9 patch](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296802/require-v8-only-contrib-module-with-v9-patch)

Comment: This is slightly related, but not the same. The other questions handles modules without Drupal 9 support (=> composer version conflict), this questions is how to include an immutable patch from the new d.o. issue queue (which does no longer provide immutable patch files).

Comment: On one hand I think: This actually is no Drupal-related problem, it's a Gitlab/GitHub-related chicken-egg-problem in general. On the other hand I think you are actually asking: How do I get the old drupal.org behaviour back with GitLab? Option 2 probably sounds like the best: Take the fork's commit patch and later break the build so you know the MR got probably merged and you can update.

Comment: @leymannx Even if it got merged, that doesn't mean there's a new release available.

Answer (score 4):

It has been discussed already in the Opt-in to the Drupal.org Issue Forks and Merge Requests beta thread, see [3152637#comment-13820062](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalorg/issues/3152637#comment-13820062).  As of now there is no straight way to integrate commits in composer patch work flow. You need to download the patch file manually by appending `.patch` to the merge request URL and copy it locally into your project to get it applied in the build process.

```
"patches": {
    "drupal/foobar": {
        "3200808 - Lorem ipsum": "./patches/3200808-3.patch"
    }
}
```

You can get additional information on how to generate patch from the commit Id from the guide: [Patch files for use with Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-git-to-contribute-to-drupal/creating-issue-forks-and-merge-requests#s-patch-files-for-use-with-composer).

Comment: One should use the `.diff` suffix instead of `.patch` because the latter will give you a commit-by-commit version which doesn't always apply.

Answer (score 0):

See Drupal documentation to force module installion due to composer restriction. There two options:

- Using Issue Forks directly
- OR Use the composer-drupal-lenient Package

@see https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-gitlab-to-contribute-to-drupal/core-version-compatibility-fixes-for-modules-with-unmerged-changes