# Installing a v8 module

Tags: composer, 9

If a contrib module's info.yml contains `core: 8.x` and not `core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9`, how can a site be upgraded to Drupal 9 using composer?

`composer update` downloads modules in `"require": {` which needs to be before `"patches": {` because there needs to be a module before it can be patched. Assume the patch patches the info.yml file with `core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9`.

So `composer update` can't resolve to an installable set of packages and throws errors like this:

```
- Root composer.json requires drupal/entity_jump_menu 1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/entity_jump_menu[1.1.0].
- drupal/entity_jump_menu 1.1.0 requires drupal/core ~8.0 -> found drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9.1).
```

It looked like the answer was changing `drupal/core` and `drupal/core-dev` to a value of `"^8.8||^9.1"`. composer update will now run, except the site is still building in version 8.9.13.

---

Following the suggestions on the [mediacurrent](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/how-fix-catch-22-problem-drupal-9-fixes-composer/) blog post, I changed composer.json to the following

```
  "repositories": [
      {
          "type": "composer",
          "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8",
          "exclude": ["drupal/entity_jump_menu"]
      },
      {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "git@git.drupal.org:issue/entity_jump_menu-3130218.git"
      }
  ],
  "require": {
      ...
      "drupal/entity_jump_menu": "dev-3130218-drupal-9-deprecated",
      ...   
  },
```

Which downloads the fork of the module, into `vendor/drupal/entity_jump_menu`. Unfortunately Drupal and/or Drush don't see the module in that directory.

I'm going to try the [computerminds](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/apply-drupal-9-compatibility-patches-composer) solution next.

---

The solution from [computerminds](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/apply-drupal-9-compatibility-patches-composer) adds the fork of the module to the modules/contrib directory. Here's the code.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "drupal/entity_jump_menu",
            "type": "drupal-module",
            "version": "dev-3130218-drupal-9-deprecated",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "git@git.drupal.org:issue/entity_jump_menu-3130218.git",
                "reference": "268adc649cfb4ad716751a8643e60f5df4dbb80d"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    ...
    "drupal/entity_jump_menu": "dev-3130218-drupal-9-deprecated",
    ...
},
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You could help to fix the contributed module ... I'm not sure why that wouldn't be the first and best option.

Comment: Modules can be minimally maintained or even abandoned. A module without, minimally, `core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9` is a show stopper for Drupal 9.

Comment: There are also modules their `core_version_requirement` key includes Drupal 9, when those modules are still using functions/methods/classes already removed from Drupal 9. Probably, helping to fix modules is a better option, as @anonymous said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to fork the module. This is more of a pain than patching but it's much better now that you can make [issue forks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-git-to-contribute-to-drupal/creating-issue-forks-and-merge-requests) on drupal.org.

Here's a [detailed tutorial](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/how-fix-catch-22-problem-drupal-9-fixes-composer/).

The basic workflow is this:

1. Make an issue fork on drupal.org that updates the version requirement.
2. Add the forked repo to your `composer.json` and update your site that way.
3. When the module gets a real Drupal 9 release, switch your `composer.json` back to the release.

Comment: While this is a possible solution, it isn't actually necessary to fork the repo,   [the answer in the linked question explains how to do](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/296916/74024)