# How do I include composer.libraries.json in root composer.json without using the wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin plugin?

Tags: webforms, composer

In the recent update to Composer 2.0 the advice is to get rid of the wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin, which was [even removed from the dependencies of Drupal core](https://www.drupal.org/node/3069730).

There is documentation on how to include custom module's composer.json in the root composer.json, for example [Managing dependencies for a custom project](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/managing-dependencies-for-a-custom-project), but I cannot find documentation on how to include composer.libraries.json in the root composer.json.

Can anyone explain how to get the Webform module compatible with Composer 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

here is a specific way how to do it for webform module.

1. run composer require wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin
2. in composer add

> ```
>   "merge-plugin": {
>             "include": [
>                 "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
>             ]
>         },
> ```

3. run composer update --lock and verify the files

Reference https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-frequently-asked-questions/how-to-use-composer-to-install-libraries

Reference 2 https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/using-the-composer-merge-plugin-to-download-libraries-with

Github issue https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin/issues/184

Comment: The question seems to explicitly ask for how to **not use the wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin**.

Comment: Hi Ales, thank you for the response. Indeed, as Leymannx says the question is how to not use the wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin... So unfortunately your solution does not work. This is how it is implemented now, but not how it should be implemented according to composer 2.0.

Comment: As Ales referenced, there is a GitHub issue for Composer Merge Plugin to be compatible with Composer 2, which has been fixed and it now is, so maybe this is the best answer after all.

Comment: Is it really fixed? In the last comments of the issue there are still people having errors...

Comment: If your composer update doesn't work to add the dependencies to your lock file, then you can run this command: composer update --with-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The alternate ways [are documented](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/webform/webform-libraries). I think the one you would prefer is:

> Execute `drush webform:composer:update`, to update your Drupal installation's composer.json to include the Webform module's selected libraries as repositories.