# How do I install my own, custom module dependant on Composer?

Tags: 9, composer

I've looked all over, but there seems to be no advice on this online.

I've recently updated a Drupal 8 site to Drupal 9. I wasn't using composer before, and so I've used composerize-drupal to make the site composer compatible.

I have my own custom module on the site, and I had to uninstall it to get the composerize-drupal and then the upgrade to work.

I'm now trying to reinstall it, but there is a complete lack of guidance on this coming up in google searches, and if I just upload it to the site as before, the site breaks.

Can anybody please help shed some light on how this can be done on a Compserized Drupal 9 site?

Comment: If the custom module has dependencies they wont be installed. Refer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/276292/how-can-i-require-a-custom-module-hosted-elsewhere-with-its-contrib-dependencies/299105#299105

Answer (score 2):

In `composer.json` you tell Composer in which directories it should put certain types of dependencies.

```json
"installer-paths": {
    "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
    "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
    "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
    "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
    "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
    "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
},
```

These directories are now managed by Composer. For example `web/modules/contrib` for type `drupal-module` dependencies. While at the same time everything put in `web/modules/custom` or any other custom location will be preserved.

Your repo in the end basically only contains the `composer.json/lock` files at the repo root and all custom code (custom themes, custom modules, custom scripts, custom patches etc.) and config YAML files in their desired directories.

---

You should gamble around a bit with the official [recommended-project template](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project/blob/9.3.3/composer.json) or the community [drupal-project template](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project). Learn to read the `composer.json` file. Run `composer install`, manually delete certain directories, `composer install` again and observe what happens.

Answer (score 1):

`composerize-drupal` creates the following directories for Composer dependencies:

- `[drupal-root]/modules/contrib`
- `[drupal-root]/themes/contrib`
- `[drupal-root]/profiles/contrib`

By convention (or at least the convention I follow), custom stuff goes in a `custom` directory.

- `[drupal-root]/modules/custom`
- `[drupal-root]/themes/custom`
- `[drupal-root]/profiles/custom`